# How to parameterize h:commandLink action attribute via ui:param

Tags: jsf, facelets, uiinclude, methodexpression

I am trying to parametrize the `action` attribute of `<h:commandLink>` in an include file:

```
<ui:include src="template-file.xhtml">
     <ui:param name="actionToCall" value="actionSave" />
     <ui:param name="actionLabel" value="actionLabel" />
</ui:include>
```

Where the `template-file.xhtml` contains:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{actionToCall}" value="#{actionLabel}" />
```

but I am getting the following exception:

```
javax.el.ELException: /page.xhtml @17,45 action="#{actionToCall}": 
     Identity 'actionToCall' does not reference a MethodExpression instance, 
     returned type: java.lang.String
```

I want it to call the spring web flow transition action I put in the `actionToCall` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `.toString` after the variable. This gives it a "method expression" (which it is looking for) and allows it to pass through and execute the desired call. The tag ends up looking like:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{actionToCall.toString}" value="#{actionLabel}" />
```

Comment: Clever trick. This works however only if you abuse POST for navigation.

Comment: It's just an AJAX call to open an edition modal panel :) I have two tabs and two very similar tables but I wanted to call two different Spring WebFlow actions from each table.